# How to add the code when I ask questions on stack overflow?

Tags: discussion

How do I add the codes, when I ask questions on stack overflow?.
I tried to copy it from MyEclipse or type `Ctrl + K` according to its reminder but failed.

Comment: press enter twice then indent the lines by at least 4 spaces

Answer (score 4):

Copy the Code from Code Editor.
`// .. Code Copied.`

And then Paste the code in the question area.
`// .. Code Pasted.`

Now Select the Entire Code.
`// .. All Code --> Selected.`

And **Press** `Ctrl + K`

Then You will see that your Code is Converted from simple Text to Code Format.

Answer (score 0):

When you press  {} icon you will  get   `enter code here`description, Copy your code there

[image]